# How to modify the reading/parsing of an Excel Column in a data Frame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to process an Excel file with Pandas. The filter to be applied is by the values of the "Test Code" column which has the format "XX10.X/XX12.X" (i.e: EF10.1). The problem is that the dataframe and neglects everything after the dot when reading the column, leaving just "XX10". The information after the dot is the most important information.

The original document classifies those cells as a date, which probably is altering the normal processing of the values.

[excelfile](https://zenodo.org/record/5155136/files/H2020_TRI-HP_T6.2_PropaneIceFaultTests_v1.xlsx?download=1)

The code I am using is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
file = "H2020_TRI-HP_T6.2_PropaneIceFaultTests_v1"
folder = "J:\Downloads"
file_path = os.path.join(folder,file+".xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name="NF10")
df["Test Code"]
```

The output is:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRc44.png)

Comment: Perhaps by specifying `dtype` in `read_excel`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I tried changing it to string and object type, it did not change. There must be something about how the author formatted the column's cells (as date).